# How many active players does Heroes of the Storm have?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Since I can't find it anywhere, either because Blizzard doesn't share these numbers or no one cares enough to write about it, I wonder how many monthly active players does HotS currently have?

Is it really dying as everyone says?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because requests for real-time data are not appropriate for a Q&A format. What happens to this question months from now? Years? Questions should stay relevant over time, and this will not.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I think that the methodology used to guesstimate the data by counting the total number of players on third party sites can be useful in the future. Also, OP did not mention anything about real-time data, but of 'active players', which can be taken to mean the common metric of 'monthly active users'.

Comment: I don't see the need to close this question. Even in the future @Yuu answer will still be relevant since it shows how to track the number of active players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of September 2018, there were [6.5 million monthly active players](https://twinfinite.net/gallery/most-played-games-ranked-monthly-players/5/).

But I assume that you meant to include '**now**' in your question, in which case it is impossible to know as Blizzard doesn't publish that data.

However, we can guesstimate it with third party data collection sites like HotsLogs. I have calculated that in the US region alone, at least 20,500 players have played 1 or more Quick Match games in the past month (and at least 10 or more in total). [You can check that by counting the number of players in every league](https://www.hotslogs.com/Rankings?Region=1&GameMode=3). If we multiply that for every region, we can estimate that there are at least 100,000 players every month.

Given that only people who upload/use the site will be included in the data, and people who have played less than 10 matches / only play the other modes do not get included in the data, I think that the actual number is several times higher. But we can only guess the actual number.

Comparing that to League of Legends with 80 million monthly active players, it might seem very few, but I would say that it is far from 'dying'.

Comment: Thanks mate! Yes, indeed I meant the number of active players now. If by only players whose use the site is around 100k per month I can only guess it has much much more since I alone and more 3 friends of mine never used it and guessing there are many more that also doesn't share this data. Love to see it still has a lot of players! Btw, why are we getting downvotes? Are we doing something wrong?

Comment: @TheBarnacle Glad that the data analysis helped! Not sure about the downvotes, stackexchange is pretty trigger-happy in that regard.

Comment: It did! Wonder why did Blizzard stopped tracking the official numbers tho. Yeah, I can see that ahaha, I got 2 downvotes not knowing why.

Comment: @TheBarnacle I'm pretty sure that Blizzard, like any other game company is still tracking the numbers, just not publishing them. Since they are keeping the game alive with relatively frequent updates (compared to DotA2), there should be a significant number of players that warrants them to employ people to work on the game.

Comment: +1 It still amazes me that they do frequent updates. I heard that they cut down to half their HotS team earlier this year but it doesn't show any signals of delay on updates and new game content. Glad people like this game after all.